# Confusion : Show that in a simple graph with 'n' vertices, has at least two vertices with the same number of degree.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Question : Show that in a simple graph with 'n' vertices, has at least two vertices with the same number of degree.

Solution :

(a)If there  is  no  isolated  vertices in the graph, then the degrees  take  values from  1 to (n-1)  (as  the  graph is simple).  Then  by  pigeon-hole  principle  atleast  two vertices has the same degree.

(b) If  there is  a isolated vertex, then  the degrees of the vertices take  values from  0 to (n-2)  (?  why  (n-2))  (as the graph is simple).  Then by the pigeon-hole  principle two vertices has the same degree.

My questions :

(1) In (a) & (b) how do we conclude using the pigeon-hole principle?

(2) In (b) how do we get "If  there is  a isolated vertex, then  the degrees of the vertices take  values from  0 to (n-2)"?

Comment: (1) You have $n$ vertices and $n-1$ options for their degrees, so there must be one option with at least $2$ vertices. (2) If there is an isolated vertex then no vertex can be connected to all others, so the option $n-1$ is not available.

Comment: Another way of arguing is that there are $n$ possibilities for the order of a vertex $0$ to $n-1$, but you can't have both a vertex which is connected to all the others and a vertex which is connected to no others - so any actual graph on $n$ vertices has at most $n-1$ distinct degrees, and must have two vertices of the same degree.

Comment: For (b), imagine nodes as people and edges as friendship. Within $n$ people, each can have at most $n-1$ friends (because no-one counts themselves as friends). Now, if in those $n$ people, there's one who is not friends with anybody, then everyone else can have at most $n-2$ friends.

Comment: This question has been raised many times before on this website. Have a look at the questions listed under "Related" on this page, see whether you can find an answer there.